# An edge that connects 3 vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Are there any practical situations that can be represented using a modified definition of an edge - where each edge connects three vertices instead of two?

Comment: Sure, for example the notion of three points being collinear. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph .

Comment: Would a triangle do? It sort of connects 3 vertices. Another possibility: in a directed graph one has two functions $s,t: E \to V$ called source and target. So one could up this to three functions! Then any selection of 2 of these would define a directed graph.

Comment: The relevant term is "hypergraph", which have a large literature. Edges in a hypergraph may be an arbitrary subset of the vertex set.

Comment: For now I'm building a graph structure which connects Chinese characters that form different words. Chinese words that contains two characters can be beautifully represented with traditional directed graphs where the edges connect to 2 vertices. It's already fun to learn words that way. Now I need to model a graph for words that can have 3 or more characters, that's when I need a hypergraph.

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about $3$-uniform [hypergraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph).  They will arise in a range of contexts, some of which are:

- [Steiner triple systems](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerTripleSystem.html) are $3$-uniform hypergraphs in which each pair of vertices belongs to exactly one hyperedge.
- Triangulations of surfaces (e.g. the plane).
- The problem of completing a partial triangulation of the complete tripartite graph $K_{n,n,n}$ has been shown to be [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).  [Charlie Colbourn](http://www.public.asu.edu/~ccolbou/) gave a polynomial time reduction of this problem to the problem of completing partial Latin squares, thereby showing that this problem is also NP-complete ([ref.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X%2884%2990075-1)).

These contexts are more areas of pure mathematics, and can be rephrased to not be $3$-uniform hypergraphs (however, I'm guessing all $3$-uniform hypergraph problems can be thus rephrased).

Combinatorial designs, such as Steiner triple systems, have applications in software testing.  Hypergraphs in general arise in the study of complex networks, but I haven't seen the particular case of $3$-uniform hypergraphs arise.

However, we don't need applications for mathematics to be interesting; the following quote applies to mathematics as well as physics.

> Physics is like sex. Sure you can get some interesting results, but that's not why we do it.  -- Richard Feynman ([disputed](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman)).